# nodejs: IJavascript: says module not found

Tags: node.js, ijavascript

I have installed Ijavascript on linux pc

```
sudo npm install -g ijavascript
```

And i have installed the `mathsteps` package

```
sudo npm install -g mathsteps
```

Now i try to open ijsnotebook

```
ijsnotebook
```

I started a javascript(node.js) shell

[image]

And now i am trying the following code example from https://github.com/google/mathsteps#usage

```
const mathsteps = require('mathsteps');

const steps = mathsteps.simplifyExpression('2x + 2x + x + x');

steps.forEach(step => {
    console.log("before change: " + step.oldNode.toString());   // before change: 2 x + 2 x + x + x
    console.log("change: " + step.changeType);                  // change: ADD_POLYNOMIAL_TERMS
    console.log("after change: " + step.newNode.toString());    // after change: 6 x
    console.log("# of substeps: " + step.substeps.length);      // # of substeps: 3
});
```

I get this error:

[image]

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'mathsteps'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:655:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:19
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:124:20)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:314:38)
    at run ([eval]:1054:15)
    at onRunRequest ([eval]:888:18)
    at onMessage ([eval]:848:13)
```

How can i solve this error. I want to check this code.

Comment: Possibly related to global modules. Try locally (in a directory, without `sudo` and `-g`) and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

First I tried a global installation, and encountered same issue. However, after I did a local install, I don't have problem with declaring `const mathsteps = require('mathsteps');` anymore.

In their repo, I have found an explanation written by the author:

> iJavascript only sees the packages local to itself and those local to the user

You can find the whole conversation here: [Set up working directory](https://github.com/n-riesco/ijavascript/issues/4)

[image: working with local node modules]

Comment: Is there a way to import d3 library like this? I keep failing.